# Memory stress test does not work

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to do a memory stress test.But it does not work well.It had returned results but it had some information about something else.And when I use a bash shell to monitor the usage of memory I tested,memory usage information did not rise quickly and it had few changes.Even if using top command in ubuntu.I use a monitoring bash shell or top command when I run the stress test bash shell called mallocBomb01.sh.The bash shell script is here.

```
#!/bin/bash 
i=1;
while [ $i -le 200 ]
do
    ./mallocBomb -i
done
```

And the result of the bash shell script is here.

...

./malloc01.sh: line 7: 105832 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./mallocBomb -i

...

And the c code of mallocBomb is here.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main(int argc,char **argv[])
{
        int count = 0;
        if(argc == 1)
                printf("Usage : ./mallocBomb <[infinite] -i>  or ./mallocBomb <itterations>");
        else
        {
                int i=0,k=0;
                if(strcmp((const char *)argv[1],"-i") == 0)
                {
                        while(1)
                        {
                            if(strcmp((const char *)argv[2],"-v") == 0)
                            {
                                    printf("Itteration count : %d\n",count++);
                            }
                            if(calloc(1,1024) != NULL)
                            {
                                    if(errno == EAGAIN)
                                    {
                                            printf("WARNING EAGAIN: Limit on the total number of processes has been reached\n");
                                    }
                                    else if(errno == ENOMEM)
                                    {
                                            printf("WARNING ENOMEM: There is not enough swamp space\n");
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                }
                else
                {
                        k =atoi((const char *)argv[1]);
                        for(i=0; i < k; i++)
                        {
                            if(strcmp((const char *)argv[2],"-v") == 0)
                            {
                                    printf("Itteration count : %d\n",i+1);
                            }
                            if(calloc(1,1024) != NULL)
                            {
                                    if(errno == EAGAIN)
                                    {
                                            printf("WARNING EAGAIN: Limit on the total number of processes has been reached\n");
                                    }
                                    else if(errno == ENOMEM)
                                    {

                                              printf("WARNING ENOMEM: There is not enough swamp space\n");
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

The results show that it has a segmentation fault (core dumped).Is it an error?If not,why did not the memory usage rise?

Comment: (1) please post text, not images of text; (2) what do you expect a program called "mallocBomb" to do? (3) we can't comment on the behaviour unless you show the source code for mallocBomb; (4) how and _when_ are you monitoring memory?

Comment: I have edited agin.Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if less than two arguments are provided on the command line?  Consider using [`getopt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html#Getopt)

Comment: I expect to have the results that make the memory usage rise as I do the memory stress tests where I use command ./malloc01.sh.Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but your program has undefined behaviour and probably crashes before allocating anything.  And you would see exactly where this happens if you attached a debugger such as `gdb` and got a stack trace after crashing.

Comment: `argv[2]` is accesed but not defined by the command line in the bash script.  Check `argc` before accessing `argv`.